# Matlab Builder JA libtbb.dylib error

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

I've been trying to run the hello world example in Java, compiled using Matlab Builder JA
on an Intel Mac with Snow Leopard. When i run the .jar on the terminal i get the following error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: dlopen(/Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/bin/maci64/libnativemcl.jnilib, 9): 
Library not loaded: libtbb.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/bin/maci64/libut.dylib
Reason: image not found
  at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.DynamicLibraryUtils.dlopen(Native Method)
  at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.DynamicLibraryUtils.loadLibraryAndBindNativeMethods(DynamicLibraryUtils.java:131)
  at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.<clinit>(MWMCR.java:1554)
  at hellopck.HellopckMCRFactory.newInstance(HellopckMCRFactory.java:49)
  at hellopck.HellopckMCRFactory.newInstance(HellopckMCRFactory.java:60)
  at hellopck.hellocls.main(hellocls.java:114)
```

I guess it has something to do with my environment variables but i can't find the exact problem. My environment vars are set as:

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH= /Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/runtime/maci64
                   :/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v715/bin

XAPPLRESDIR= /Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/X11/app-defaults

I 've seen a few similar posts but non of the solutions seems to work

Comment: how much does Matlab Builder JA cost? Are there freeware alternatives that do the same -or similar- thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I 've set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH as follows and it worked.

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH= :/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v715/runtime/maci64:
/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v715/bin/maci64:
/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v715/sys/os/maci64

Answer (score 0):

The DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable you listed,

> > DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH= /Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/runtime/maci64 :/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v715/bin

has a space in it (after `maci64` and before `:/Applications`). If that is not a typo in your question, then I think it could be the problem.